# Android use Log to add information to crash reports

Tags: android, logging, crash-reports

I would like to know if it is possible to use the Log family of functions to include extra information in crash reports. There are many Log versions, Log.e, Log.d, Log.v, Log.i, Log.w, but I cannot find much difference between them.

Would using any of these functions cause the message to be added to a user-submitted crash report similar to the way that in the Logcat messages are listed in chronological order so Log statements can print information to logcat just before a crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e, d, v, i, w is mean "Error", "Debug", "Verbose", "Info", "Warn" is error level.
So you can choose level correctly, print log. almost crash is displayed "Fatal" level.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I am want to understand more how they different in function. Does having your log message labeled by different error levels change how it is logged? What about the fatal level? I would really like to know if a severely-labeled message would show up with the stack trace when a user submits a bug report.